# How to get twitter user timeline in C# using Twitterizer

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, twitter, twitterizer

i have the following code.

```
 
Twitter t1 = new Twitter("twitteruser","password");
                TwitterUser user =  t1.User.Show("username");
                if (user != null)
                {
                    TwitterParameters param = new TwitterParameters();
                    param.Add(TwitterParameterNames.UserID, user.ID);
                    TwitterStatusCollection t =t1.Status.UserTimeline(param);                   
                }
```

In the above code, I want to get user timeline. I am using Twitterizer API. The twitter documentation for getting timeline of user is [Here](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-REST-API-Method%3A-statuses-user_timeline)

I have checked the fiddler whats going on. In fiddler the request is :

http://api.twitter.com/1/direct_messages.xml?user_id=xxxxx

while i am expecting

http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline.format

Is anything left which i miss.

Comment: It would help if you'd say what you're seeing compared with what you expect to see.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bug in the latest version of the Twitterizer Library.

I will try to get this corrected and post an update today.

If you run into any other issues, please contact the Twitterizer group directly, on our site ([http://www.twitterizer.net/](http://www.twitterizer.net)) you'll find links to our mailing list, twitter account, and you can submit but reports directly to our team.

Ricky (Twitterizer founder)

Comment: The update has been posted (you're the first to be told). Please go download version 1.0.146:
http://code.google.com/p/twitterizer/downloads/list

Answer (score 3):

Here's how to get a user's timeline without using oAuth or *any* authentication, for that matter:

```
UserTimelineOptions options = new UserTimelineOptions();
options.ScreenName = "SCREENNAME OF TWITTER USER";
TwitterStatusCollection tweets = TwitterTimeline.UserTimeline(options).ResponseObject;
```

Comment: Your code is correct, however developer should consider authenticating more often than not. Using OAuth provides 350 requests per hour PER USER, whereas non-authenticated requests are limited to 100 requests per hour PER IP ADDRESS.

Answer (score 0):

I have to agree with Eric. I only looked at Twitterizer for a few hours, and I have not found one example that shows how to load a user's timeline without authorization.

Will I figure it out eventually? Yeah, I'll have to and I will; but it will take me forever.

The link that Ricky Smith gave (twitterizer.net) doesn't have this kind of simple example. The tutorials available on the internet that I found for twitterizer2, even those are not up-to-date and don't quite work or are missing information.

Ricky, how about being a lifesaver to me and others and showing us how to simply look at a user's public timeline, so there's no need for authorization? Whaddya'say?

Comment: Try this: `TwitterTimeline.UserTimeline(new UserTimelineOptions() { ScreenName = "twitterapi" };`